# Fly-in animation only on focus

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I want to create the **fly-in** effect only on **focus of the block** with a certain class (and not on page load), in an Angular application.
This without jquery or other libraries, possibly (i searched but found practically only solutions with jquery, which I am not using on my Angular app).
I ask with Angular tag because I am in an Angular application but maybe there is also a way with just css?

One example that doesn't work on focus but on page load:

```css
#first-page {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100%;
}
#second-page {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.fly-in-block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  transform: translateX(-600%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%);
}
.flyIn {
  animation: flyIn 0.8s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: flyIn 0.8s forwards;
}
@keyframes flyIn {100% { transform: translateX(0%); }}
@-webkit-keyframes flyIn {100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }}
```

```html
<div id="first-page">
  First page
</div>
<div id="second-page">
  Second page
  <div class="fly-in-block flyIn"></div>
</div>
```

Here a link to the Angular snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fly-in-animation-on-focus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with focus. Are you looking for something like this? You can probably adapt it to your needs.

See in the html I removed the `flyIn` class and add it via js only when the block is scrolled into view.

Once the animation is triggered the listener is removed.

```js
const block = document.querySelector( '.fly-in-block' )
const blockOffset = block.offsetTop

const triggerAnimation = () => {
  const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight
  if( scrollHeight >= blockOffset ) {
    block.classList.add( 'flyIn' )
    window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', triggerAnimation )
  }
}

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', triggerAnimation )
```

```css
#first-page {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100%;
}
#second-page {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.fly-in-block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  transform: translateX(-600%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%);
}
.flyIn {
  animation: flyIn 0.8s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: flyIn 0.8s forwards;
}
@keyframes flyIn {100% { transform: translateX(0%); }}
@-webkit-keyframes flyIn {100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }}
```

```html
<div id="first-page">
  First page
</div>
<div id="second-page">
  Second page
  <div class="fly-in-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's what I need, thanks. It is a pity that there is no solution only in CSS but maybe I'm asking too much.